# Does Apple approve a kind of mark-up language for AppStore?

Tags: appstore-approval

AppStore now rejects applications made with non-Apple like languages. (with modified contract)

However, is it allowed using declarative mark-up language formed with XML? (like XHTML, but different schema) The declarative mark-up is a code too, but not a script or logic code. Just a passive, static data, but forms some layout and part of an application logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to make an application based on XHTML/XML and show that data, isn't it better to make a webbase application for it? Maybe using webkit for it?

If you mean using XML in your application than this shouldn't be a problem, most applications do. In fact, XIB (nib) files are XML files to as are property files (plist).